# mysql select latest timestamp in a group

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, groupwise-maximum

I have a table for which I would like to select the most recent time stamp in a category defined by the value of a particular column in the table.

Specifically

```
SELECT * 
FROM   takelist 
WHERE  producer_name = 'sean' 
       AND bucket_id = '2CCEx15_1o'
```

results in

```
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
| takelist_id | producer_name | bucket_id  | ts                  |
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
|           1 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-10-07 18:29:00 |
|           4 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-10-07 18:33:09 |
|           5 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-10-07 18:33:38 |
|          27 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-10-07 18:37:38 |
|         212 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-10-14 18:36:05 |
|         236 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-10-21 17:59:56 |
|         237 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-10-21 18:00:55 |
|         281 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-10-29 15:58:40 |
|         287 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-10-29 19:24:15 |
|         330 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-10-31 14:39:33 |
|         615 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-12-16 22:46:59 |
|         616 | sean          | 2CCEx15_1o | 2013-12-16 22:54:46 |
+-------------+---------------+------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to select one row for each unique value of the column named bucket_id where the selected row has the most recent timestamp.

I have tried the below based upon previous answers to similar question but must have got something wrong

```
SELECT takes.* FROM takelist as takes 
INNER JOIN (         
            SELECT takelist_id, max(ts) max_ts, bucket_id
            FROM takelist 
            WHERE producer_name='sean' 
            GROUP BY bucket_id
             ) latest_take
ON takes.takelist_id=latest_take.takelist_id
AND takes.ts=latest_take.max_ts
```

Comment: Your subquery is relying on MySQL-specific behavior, and your statement will cause most/all other RDBMSs to throw a syntax error: you list a column that is neither in the `GROUP BY` nor an aggregate function (like `MAX()`).  In MySQL, the contents of `takelist_id` in this case are essentially "undetermined" - it depends heavily on what indices you have defined, what queries are executing, etc, and is completely up to the whim of the optimizer.  There's not a good way to guarantee specific behavior in this case, so try to avoid using this "feature".

Answer (score 5):

Your query is close.  But you are using the id instead of the timestamp:

```
SELECT takes.*
FROM takelist takes INNER JOIN
     (SELECT max(ts) as max_ts, bucket_id
      FROM takelist 
      WHERE producer_name = 'sean' 
      GROUP BY bucket_id
     ) latest_take
     ON takes.ts = latest_take.max_ts and takes.bucket_id = latest_take.bucket_id;
```

An arbitrary `takelist_id` is chosen in the original formulation.  And it might not be the one you want.

Comment: @user3145007 What will be the case if `bucket_id` changes? As per me for all bucket_ids this query will check only TIMESTAMP with takelist table so it is possible that query returns more than one record per bucket_ids.

Comment: Gordon - I think you meant to add `bucket_id` to the join?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM takelist AS t 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(ts) max_ts, bucket_id
            FROM takelist WHERE producer_name='sean' 
            GROUP BY bucket_id
           ) lt ON t.bucket_id=lt.bucket_id AND t.ts=lt.max_ts;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM takelist WHERE producer_name='sean' ORDER BY bucket_id, ts DESC) A 
GROUP BY bucket_id
```

Comment: Please note that I'd be _extremely_ leery of your second option, as I'm not sure that the expected behavior (getting the "top row per group") is guaranteed.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse In MySQL is guaranteed as per my experience with MySQL.

Comment: What if instead of providing a literal value you're simply grouping by the ```bucked_id```?